# HTML and CSS - Centering a div no matter on browser size

Tags: css, html, centering

Why is it that what feels like it should be the most simple of tasks to me is always the most perplexing... Its in the title... but I have played for yonks but cant get it to work for me!

Essentially (just to make it even more plain I am hoping to get the following) (the image is the div background).

[image]

so whatever the size of the browser window the div is always centralised!

Thank you for any advice you can give...  [=

edit: Basically what I am trying to achieve is a cheating way of having a popout window for a registration form.

so at the moment the entire page consists of the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <title>BlurbeRella - Registeration</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 </head>
 <div id="registerpage">
  <img src="images/registerpage.png" class="registerpage" />
 </div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
img.registerpage{ 
 text-align: center;
 top: 100%;
}

#registerpage{
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}
```

the css is my feeble attempt to keep it central.....

basically: the site at the moment (with no functionality yet) is blurberella.x10.mx

when the user clicks on register I will have the background image of the site itself so it looks like you are still on the same page.. then in the middle I will have my form... but to make sure that the site image still looks like a website I need it to remain central whatever the browser size!

I hope this makes sense... I no that I am cheating at this but with my current knowledge this is the best I can pull off.... I am still learning!

Comment: Can you post some code?  Likely you will need to use a div with a width that is the same as your image and set `margin:0 auto`.  Is this for a background image?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? Are you trying to achieve the effect in the images? Is it that you want the text to stay centered and on one line, no matter how narrow the browser window?

Comment: The white dot is a background image, right? But is the red text also part of the background image, or is that a placeholder for the actual content in the div?

Comment: Do you still want the image to be centered if the image size is larger than the browser? If so you will need to use javascript.

Comment: I have edited my quesxtion to try and make more sense of it

Comment: OK, but you can't click on Register on your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood the question somewhere, but from my understanding you are looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wCvtJ/).

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="imgholder"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#imgholder {
    height: 100%;
    background: url(image.png) center center no-repeat;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** Based on your extra information, http://jsfiddle.net/EJM9J/ is what you want. Just a div like any other, only centered in the page. You can give it a background image if you want.

You will need Javascript though.

Answer (score 1):

I just did [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jnkV6/2/) for another CSS topic. See if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works on all browsers, but it should work on the newer ones.

### CSS:

```
.container {
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical
}

.content {
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-flex: 1
}
```

### HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
Stuff to be Centered
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there are some cracking responces that worked "Thank you all"

I sorted it with this

background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center;

Thank you all....

I am sorry for a poorly explained question